# Change value property of Circular gauge

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gauge

Hi I know this is a old and easy question, but I really dont get it. How can I change the value property of my circular gauge dynamicly from python to the qml file? I tried alot but standing again at the beginning. Because I am very new to QT and Python can somebody explain me how to do? I copied the qml and the empty python file here:

Python:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui



if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.load('dashboard.qml')
  win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
  win.textUpdated.connect(show)
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the QML:

```
 CircularGauge {
                    value: 66  **(Thats the value I want to change from Python)**
                    maximumValue: 1 
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height * 0.7
                    y: parent.height / 2 + container.height * 0.01

                style: IconGaugeStyle {
                    id: tempGaugeStyle

                    icon: "qrc:/images/temperature-icon.png"
                    maxWarningColor: Qt.rgba(0.5, 0, 0, 1)

                    tickmarkLabel: Text {
                        color: "white"
                        visible: styleData.value === 0 ||     styleData.value === 1
                        font.pixelSize: tempGaugeStyle.toPixels(0.225)
                        text: styleData.value === 0 ? "C" : (styleData.value === 1 ? "H" : "")
                    }
```

Thanks a lot for helping a noob :)

Actually having this python:

```
class Celsius(QObject):
    def __init__(self, temperature = 0.6):
        self._temperature = temperature


    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("Getting value")
        return self._temperature

     @temperature.setter
     def temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("Temperature below -273 is not possible")
        print("Setting value")
        self._temperature = value

rotatevalue = Celsius()
print(rotatevalue.temperature)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.load('dashboard.qml')

  view = QQuickView()
  root_context = view.rootContext().setContextProperty("valuepy", Celsius())
  win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
  win.textUpdated.connect(show)
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QML is the same. If I print rotatevalue.temperature, I have the right value in this variable but the connection to the qml is still a problem. Python says on running following:

root_context = view.rootContext().setContextProperty("valuepy", Celsius())
RuntimeError: super-class **init**() of type Celsius was never called.

And the value is not in my gauge. Any ideas?

Comment: In C++ you would create a `QObject` derived class that has a property with a type compatible to the `value` property of the QML element.
Then export an instance of that class via `engine.rootContext().setContextProperty()`
I assume this also works with Python, just not sure about the syntax for properties

Comment: Thanks for the help Mr Krammer, but I can do what I want, not getting it to work, does anybody have a simple example of writing a value from Python to qml?

Comment: The imporant part is to not "write to QML", but to expose a propery and bind to that on the QML side.

Comment: I posted an edit of my question, the question is how to do ecactly that :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that. I assume your QML is now something like `value: valuepy.temperature`?

Answer (score 0):

I am unfortunately not able to help you with the Python syntax but this is how that would look in C++

```
class Celsius : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double temperature READ temperature WRITE setTemperature NOTIFY temperatureChanged)

public:
    explicit Celsius(double temperature = 0.6, QObject *parent = 0)
        : QObject(parent), m_temperature(temperature) {}

    double temperature() const { return m_temperature; }

    void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        if (temperature == m_temperature) return;

        if (temperature < -273) return;

        m_temperature = temperature;
        emit temperatureChanged();
    }

signals:
    void temperatureChanged();
};
```

Maybe someone with PytQt know-how can propose an edit or base their own answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

For anybode having the same problem, I found out, here is the code which seems to go right, thanks a lot for all the helping:

```
class Celsius(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.temperature = 0.3


    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def temperature(self):
        return self._temperature

    # Define the setter of the 'temperature' property.
    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, temperature):
        self._temperature = temperature

rotatevalue = Celsius()
print(rotatevalue.temperature)
rot = rotatevalue.temperature


if __name__ == "__main__":

  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  qmlRegisterType(Celsius, 'Celsius', 1, 0, 'Celsius')
  view = QQuickView()
  engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
  engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('valuepy', rot)
  engine.load('dashboard.qml')
  win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is that not just exporting the single value for "rot"? I.e. if you change the property of `rotatevalue` does the value in QML change?

Comment: Do you mean it only gives the value to the qml once and not updateing when the program is running and value changes?

Comment: yes, that what it looks like, but python might be doing things differently here

Comment: Will check that as soon as possible and give a comment here.